# Query Two Different Table that have same field item

Tags: sql, join

I have two table

Table_A

```
ID  PostId  Item  Stock  Price
1   1       A     30     10
2   1       B     40     20
3   2       A     50     5
4   3       A     50     25
```

Table_B

```
ID  PostId  Item_ID    Sold    Price
1   1       1          2        20
2   1       2          2        40
3   1       1          1        10
4   2       3          3        15
5   2       3          1        5
```

I want to queries from above two table that have same 'PostID' and COUNT and SUM some field group by 'PostID', expected output would be like this

Output

```
ID  PostId  Total Item    Total Stock   Total Buyer(s)    Total Sold   Total Price
1   1       2             70            3                  5           70
```

I've try to JOIN it, but result still miss calculate

```
SELECT Table_A.PostId AS PostId, COUNT(Table_A.Item) AS Total_Item, SUM(Table_A.stock) AS Total_Stock, COUNT(Table_B.Item_ID) AS total_buyer, SUM( Table_B.Sold ) AS TotalSold, SUM( Table_B.Price ) AS Total_Price
FROM Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.PostId = Table_B.PostId
WHERE Table_A.PostId = '1'
GROUP BY Table_A.PostId
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Any suggestion for this query problem?? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table_B.PostId AS PostId, 
       MIN(Table_A.Total_Item) AS Total_Item, 
       MIN(Table_A.Total_Stock) AS Total_Stock, 
       COUNT(Table_B.Item_ID) AS total_buyer, 
       SUM( Table_B.Sold ) AS TotalSold, 
       SUM( Table_B.Price ) AS Total_Price
FROM Table_B
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT PostId,
       COUNT(Item) AS Total_Item,
       SUM(stock) AS Total_Stock
FROM
Table_A
GROUP BY PostId
) Table_A
ON Table_B.PostId=Table_A.PostId
WHERE Table_B.PostId = '1'
GROUP BY Table_B.PostId
LIMIT 0 , 30
```